# How to get Mac address of system using snmp?

Tags: snmp

I am using snmpwalk for retrieve my system(localhost) or remote system's mac address and I am using this command:

```
snmpwalk -v2c -c public localhost .1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.6
```

and get an error like `noSuchObject`.

How can I solve this error? Is there another way to get system mac address using snmp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as "system MAC address". Systems do not have MAC addresses; network interfaces do, and a system may have zero, one, two or more network interfaces.

That's why you use `snmpwalk`: because .1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.6 (i.e. `ifPhysAddress`) is a column in a *table* of interfaces and you don't know in advance how many conceptual rows you'll get back (and what unique numerical index each row will use as its key).

So, you're using the command properly. But next we have to consider that times have changed since the SNMP and SMI RFCs were written, well before the dot-com boom and back when the internet was a relatively pleasant and happy place. Nowadays, implementations tend to be far more conservative in the information they disclose, because every piece of information you disclose is potentially another way to attack your system. Why does anyone *need* access to know your system's MAC address? They probably don't. I created an SNMP Agent recently and its support for "standard" objects doesn't go anywhere near listing network interfaces. And many of the RFC1213 packet/status counters in `snmp` were deliberately made obsolete when a "safe" subset was adopted into RFC1907.

What does this mean for you? Well, the remote system must have a network interface otherwise you wouldn't be able to talk to it. So, the SNMP Agent you're polling/querying (you didn't say which) is either hardcoded or configured not to provide this information. You can't get around that, except by talking to the person who created the software and asking whether it is configurable; prepare for the answer to be "no".

Comment: Understand..Thank you.