# How to find running processes on "demo.snmplabs.com" server?

Tags: python, python-3.x, snmp, pysnmp

I'm using PYSNMP module for python to achieve the task. But, I have yet to find an OID for this.

Comment: As far as pysnmp is concerned, you can [follow this example](http://snmplabs.com/pysnmp/examples/hlapi/asyncore/sync/manager/cmdgen/table-operations.html#fetch-whole-snmp-table) to fetch the columns of the table if interest.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for the [Host Resources MIB](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2790), specifically `hrSWRunTable`.

The SNMPLabs demo server *does* respond to this, so with Net-SNMP you'd do:

```
snmptable -v2c -c public demo.snmplabs.com hrSWRunTable
```

*(On my CentOS 7 machine, `HOST-RESOURCES-MIB` is helpfully installed by default, so this should "just work" for you if you're also using Net-SNMP. Don't ask me how to plug MIBs into PySNMP though.)*

However, [like many MIBs from that era](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50238846/560648), it exposes information that would be deemed risky in modern times, so I wouldn't hold your breath finding a "real" agent that implements any of its objects!